# Get all the events associated with a particular user in facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of all the events a user has been invited to even though he has not clicked on join , accept or decline. Right now I can get a list of all the events(including the ones created by the user) by querying me/events. But this does not return the events which the user has just been invited to but the user has not interacted with the invitation just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of all the events a user has been invited to even though he has not clicked on join , accept or decline.

Yes, via the [FQL event_member table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/).

It has a field called `rsvp_status`:

> “The reply status of the user for the event being queried. There are four possible return values: attending, unsure, declined, and not_replied.”

So as you can see, it also lists events the user has not yet replied to.

You can just query it by the `uid`.